# Refresh chart on form every 100ms, System.Threading.Timer vs System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I'm using a Gantt chart in my winform application. I'm assigning many tasks that will be executed by my application. When they are due, they are executed. It's a live view of the chart for the user, and the chart will be repainted every 100ms. For this purpose I'm currently using System.Threading.Timer and Invoking the control. This I know requires context switching, and I have been thinking about using System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead, since this wouldnt require context switching.

What is the recommended timer for updating such controls on a winform?

The application will need to run for hours/days. Would there be a performance increase by switching type of timer, or does the Windows.Forms.Timer has it's downsides as well?

Comment: i think this will be a reading for you - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Comment: There's no point in using such a timer and then having to invoke.  It won't be any faster or smoother.  Sure, use the Winforms Timer class.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I will take your advice...